# How to download a PDF from a given URL in Java?

Tags: java, file, pdf, download

I want to make a Java application that when executed downloads a file from a URL. Is there any function that I can use in order to do this?

This piece of code worked only for a `.txt` file:

```
URL url= new URL("http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~std10108/a.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt", "UTF-8");

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
   writer.write(inputLine+ System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));               
   System.out.println(inputLine);
}
writer.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: It's not the same since I don't want to donwload a whole site but a file of it! Thanks though!

Comment: It is the same. That question is NOT asking about how to download a whole site.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Don't use Readers and Writers here as they are designed to handle raw-text files which PDF is not (since it also contains many other information like info about font, and even images). Instead use Streams to copy all **raw bytes**.

So open connection using `URL` class. Then just read from its InputStream and write raw bytes to your file.

*(this is simplified example, you still need to handle exceptions and ensure closing streams in right places)*

```
System.out.println("opening connection");
URL url = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/87/Example.JPG");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("yourFile.jpg"));

System.out.println("reading from resource and writing to file...");
int length = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from connection
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
fos.close();
in.close();
System.out.println("File downloaded");
```

Since Java 7 we can also use `Files.copy` and the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close the InputStream (the stream doesn't have to be closed manually in this case):

```
URL url = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/87/Example.JPG");
try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
   Files.copy(in, Paths.get("someFile.jpg"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the assignment operator as the parameter of the while loop?

Comment: @louiemcconnell Yes. This logic is same as in first example from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html but instead of reading lines I am reading bytes.

Comment: I got success only calling in.readAllBytes() and returning the byteArray

but I didn't want the backend to download the file