# Download file using REST API

Tags: java, rest, api

I am trying to call a REST API using Java client.

The Rest API https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data has files data.
When I append file name to the URL (https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/556e5e3f-0ab9-4b6c-aa62-c42f6a6cf20c) I can download the given file from using browser.

here filename is `556e5e3f-0ab9-4b6c-aa62-c42f6a6cf20c`.

can you please let me know,How can i achieve in this JAVA. The code I am using.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DownloadFilesAPI {
    public DownloadFilesAPI() {
        super();
    }

    public static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl) {
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //   connection.connect();
            //Get the response status of the Rest API
            //  int responsecode = connection.getResponseCode();
            //System.out.println("Response code is: " +responsecode);
            //connection.getResponseMessage();
            // System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //  System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
            //  System.out.println( JsonPath.from(requestUrl));
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new 
            OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(requestUrl);
            writer.close(); 
            /* BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
            }
            br.close(); */
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        // values.add("556e5e3f-0ab9-4b6c-aa62-c42f6a6cf20c");
        String requestUrl = "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/556e5e3f-0ab9-4b6c-aa62-c42f6a6cf20c";
        sendPostRequest(requestUrl);
    }
    private static String preparePayload(List<String> values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : values) {
        sb.append("\"" + value + "\",");
    }
    String Requiredvalue = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1);
    return "{ \"ids\":[" + Requiredvalue + "] } } }";
    } 
}
```

Comment: I do not know if it's your issue but the file is a pdf and you set your headers to accept json.

Comment: `{
  "message": "405 Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}` Even the POST call to API doesn't work.

Comment: Do not get any exception. I just want help in modifying the code to get the file downloaded. The POST call to API works through browser when File name is appended.

Comment: A browser does a GET request, your code does a POST request.

Comment: I tried GET in postman, got file.

Comment: You are trying to download a pdf a StringBuilder won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just output a String since you are trying to download a pdf. If you simply want to download the File there is an easier method adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265740/how-to-download-a-pdf-from-a-given-url-in-java) answer:

```
    String requestUrl = "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/556e5e3f-0ab9-4b6c-aa62-c42f6a6cf20c";
    URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("your_filename.pdf"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    in.close();
    System.out.println("finished!");
```

I have tested it for the URL you provided and got the pdf File without problems.